# ng-test: show result only for passed tests

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm using angular with karma test runner. But there are to many logs there.

[image]

How can I show only test result without any other log information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The level of logging by karma can be [changed in the **`karma.conf.js`** file](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html).

Go to `karma.conf.js` and add/change the property `logLevel` to **`config.LOG_DISABLE`** if you don't want to see any logs or **`config.LOG_ERROR`** if you want to only see the errors. Like this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    ...,
    logLevel: config.LOG_ERROR,
    ...,
  })
}
```

If you are running karma from the command line you can append **`--log-level debug`** to the command for the same effect.